# change values in Datagridview when it has been binded

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project, I am trying to change values in a column of DataGridView after binding it with DataSet. Something like this:

```
dgvMain --> DataGridView
dsMainPatients --> DataSet
dsMainDoctors -->  DataSet
```

---

```
  dgvMain.DataSource = null;
  dgvMain.DataSource = dsMainPatients.Tables[0];
```

---

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvMain.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxCell txt = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    for (int intCount = 0; intCount < dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intCount++)
    {
        if (r.Cells[4].Value.ToString().Equals(dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][0].ToString()))
        {
             txt.Value = dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][1].ToString();
             r.Cells[4] = txt;   //dgvMain[4, r.Index] = txt; (also tried)
        }
    }                            
 }
```

My solution is entering in to the if statement successfully and even `txt` holds correct value but I dont know what is happening at `r.Cells[4]` that it has the same old previous value.
Everything is correct eventhough the value in the grid columns are not changing.. How to change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
    {
         for (int intCount = 0; intCount < dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intCount++)
         {
             if (e.Value.ToString().Equals(dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][0].ToString()))
             {
                  e.Value = txt.Value = dsMainDoctors.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][1].ToString();
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: try to add value to cell without this for loop. Remove for loop and just within if statement add e.Value = "test"; What is the result ?

Comment: Hey sorry, it was happening because of other problem... Now the problem is all the columns are showing `"DataGridViewTextBoxCell{ ColumnIndex = -1, RowIndex = -1 }"`.

Comment: Can you debug app and see does dsMainDoctors.Tables[0] have rows?

Comment: yes it worked. just slight change.. change `txt` to `txt.Value`. :)